# collectionviewで2種類のセル(A,B)を表示させて、Aのセルだけに配列の値を表示させる方法はありますか？

Tags: swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

画像のようにラベルに値を入れているセルと何も表示させていないセルがあるのですが、この状態だと3が何も表示させていないセルの部分(indexpath.row == 2)に入ってしまっていると思われます。
3の表示を１つずらして 1,2,何もないセル,3,4　のような表示にさせたいのですが、何か方法はありますでしょうか？ [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

セルに表示する情報は `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` で設定しているはずです。
そこで与えられた `indexPath` に対して表示して欲しい内容を設定するプログラムを書けばよいだけです。
この場合、 3番目のセル、つまり `indexPath.item == 2` の場合だけ空欄のセルにしたいなら

```
if indexPath.item < 2 {
    cell.label.text = "\(indexPath.item + 1)"
} else if indexPath.item == 2 {
    cell.label.text = ""
} else {
    cell.label.text = "\(indexPath.item)"
}
```

のように分岐すれ処理を書けばよいだけのように思います。
（cellにlabelというUILabel型プロパティがあると仮定。実際はご自分のプログラムにあわせてください）